# binding checkbox in datatemplate to user control datacontext

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a listbox which include a data template of checkbox. I need the check box data context be the user control and not the listbox datacontext. How can active that in silverlight since donot have relativesource than self or template

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight does not have relative source binding "out of the box", however there is a solution here that works:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/

You can bind your CheckBox's DataContext to that of the parent User Conntrol (In this example it is called MyUserControl) as follows:

```
  <CheckBox>
      <local:BindingHelper.Binding>
          <local:BindingProperties TargetProperty="DataContext" 
                   SourceProperty="DataContext"
                   RelativeSourceAncestorType="MyUserCOntrol"/>
      </local:BindingHelper.Binding>
  </CheckBox>
```

If you do not want to go down this route, you could create a ViewModel that exposes a collection of objects that you bind to your checkbox, each object could provide a reference back to the parent view model.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply .
But the checkbox inside a data template , and if I bind it to the usercontrol datacontext I'll loose the checkbox text . So one have I have to keep the list binding to still display the checkboxes text and in the other hand I need the usercotrol context because the command inside it .

Comment: Did you finally find a solution? I have exactly the same problem.